# Demo PHP code and URL when call is answered - application error has occurred

Tags: php

In the PHP demo, the URL that is requested is not a page, but rather a directory.  I'm not sure what file is actually being served up on the server side in this example.

To create my own response file, I put up an XML file on google drive (and shared it publicly) and pointed the demo code at that file, but when my phone rings and I press a number, I just get 'an application error has occurred).  I haven't been able to find any docs relating to what I might be doing wrong in the response file.

The XML code:

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice U R L to change this message.</Say>
    <Pause length="1"/>
    <Say voice="alice">Let us know if we can help you in any way during your development.</Say>
</Response>
```

Demo URL:
http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice

My URL:
https://96932a34a3ca7871e3e02fdaf2ee1d913b81c058.googledrive.com/host/0BwlUX8TTltdsLVBlQ042Yi1iYlU/voice.xml

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post URLs to remote source code. Isolate the problematic code and post it here.

Comment: My concern is that the problem is not the code itself (as it's pretty much cut/paste right from the Demo code so I'm sure that's not the issue) but that there may be an issue with the URL and using google drive for hosting.  Without the URL, I don't think the community will be able to help me.

Comment: Here is the code, but I don't think there is any issue with it (other than trying to figure out how to format it to be readable in this forum).
<Response>
<Say voice="alice">
Hello David. This is an automated message from Robert generated by Twilio.
</Say>
<Pause length="1"/>
<Say voice="alice">I will hang up now.</Say>
</Response>

Comment: Ok, I see. I've taken the liberty to put the code into the post anyway; it doesn't hurt. More important: What application do you use to process those files? I guess that it's some sort of TTS library, not plain PHP. Please update your post accordingly, this will make it easier for others to understand your environment.

Comment: I'm starting VERY basic here.  IIS with PHP.  Downloaded the code samples that Twilio provided.  I just used notepad to edit the code sample provided by Twilio to change my phone numbers and the token.  Then tested and it worked fine.  However I wanted to change the message that is played when my phone receives the test call.  For that I need to host my own response file instead of using Twilio's hosted demo file.  I cant host it on our internal IIS server as it needs to be available externally, so created the XML file (via cut/paste) and stuck it up on google drive and shared it out publicly.

Comment: I would sincerely recommend you to update your post with all of that information. Do by all means mention that you're using Twilio and their APIs/SDKs, maybe even in the title (just posting some URL doesn't make that clear). Also consider adding some more specific tags. Your post in its current state is very vague and very unlikely to attract someone knowledgable about this topic.

Comment: By the way, if the exact same XML file works when retrieved from one server, but doesn't work when retrieved from another one, it could have to do with the headers. But without error messages this is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Moved the XML file from google drive over to a 'real' web host and it worked fine.  Lesson learned is don't use google drive for hosting pages.